# Viewport Height/Width on Tablet Strange Behaviour

Tags: html, css, meteor, viewport, viewport-units

For the entirety of my web application (built with Meteor.js) I have used viewport height (vh) and viewport width (vw) units for various elements in my HTML. I also have overflow hidden on my `body` element because many of my absolute-positioned elements are partially off of the page.

On Desktop browsers, it works fine - viewport units work and the overflow hidden works on the body. However, as soon as I start using iPad views, I get very strange behaviour, as demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

I start getting a scroll on the body, and the content within it only occupies about 95% of it with the bottom of the body showing below.

In my HTML header, I have put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`. My body element css looks like this:

```
body {
    background: #000000;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

When I add e.g. `html { overflow: hidden; }` I get even stranger behaviour, whereby some of my absolute-positioned elements partially off the page don't even render. Again, this behaviour is only on tablet views.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I would not suggest using `vw` and `vh` for equal presentation purposes across multiple device types. They simply don't work as expected at all times. You should stick to `em` or `rem` units with a base font-size ratio for your whole document.

Comment: @Sqnkov I know this thanks, but given that I have used the viewport dimensions, do you by chance know a potential solution? Thanks.